# Can I push an image built in Cloud Build to an image registry that is not Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, cicd

Using Cloud Build, can I push the resulting image to a different image registry rather than gcr.io?

Comment: Yes, you can use docker push command and push elsewhere. What did you try?

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb now. After sleeping on it I see now that I could define a step in cloudbuild.yaml which `args` were `push ...` and that would push the image elsewhere. I got mislead by the comment on the `images` stanza, which says:

"# By default, all built docker images will be lost once the build is complete.
# Rather than writing a build step to push this image, you can simply **list the
# image below and it will automatically be uploaded to Google Cloud Container
# Registry.**
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/helloworld-image'

Comment: Note the **rather than** hehehe 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your build produces artifacts such as binaries or tarballs, you can choose to store them in Cloud Storage or any private third-party repository.

You can check [this example](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/interacting-with-dockerhub-images#pushing_images_to_docker_hub) to push images to Docker Hub. Note in the example build config file that ***REPOSITORY*** is the name of your Docker repository to which you're pushing the image. You should try similar steps in order to push the resulting image to a private image registry.

Doing this could also imply building repositories as in the [repositories from GitHub](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-github) and from [repositories from GitHub Enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-github-enterprise) .